# Why does my Timer crashes my android activity when I stop it?

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I'm trying to make a toggle button that can stop and replay a Timer, it worked just fine until I added a new method called "Set_BPM".
It starts and it stops correctly, it crashes when I try to start it again after I stopped it.

**This is the class where I'm using the Timer:**

```
public class Metronome {

int miliseconds;
Timer timer = new Timer();

public Metronome () { }

public void Set_BPM (int bpm) {
    miliseconds = (60000 / bpm);
}

public void Start (final Context context) {
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Sonidos.Tick(context);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, miliseconds);
}
public void Stop () {
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
}
}
```

And this is how I'm calling it:

```
public void Encender_Metronomo (View view) {
    if (tb_metronome.isChecked()) {
        metronome.Set_BPM(Integer.parseInt(et_bpm.getText().toString()));
        metronome.Start(this);
    }
    else
        metronome.Stop();

    Sonidos.Button(this);
}
```

**There's also this object on top of my Activity:**

```
private Metronome metronome = new Metronome();
```

[image: This is what Logcat says]

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I added an image about that

Comment: In the future, please post stack traces as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you `cancel()` a `Timer`, you cannot schedule more tasks with it. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#cancel()):

> Once a timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.

Comment: Thank you, I created a new object every time I canceled the Timer